# How to go to an already existing activity from a different one

Tags: android, android-activity

To start off I am new to Android programming. I have a pretty straight forward question and I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Say I have 2 `Activity`s called `A` and `B` and both getting started, how do i switch the `Activity`s without declaring a new instance of the `Activity`s and without hitting the back button. in both `Activity`s I have a global reference to the other one. do I use the `setVisible()` method? the documentations didn't seem to clear me up about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> > do i use the setVisible method?

No. That will only work on inflated `Views/layouts`. The `layout` that is in whichever `Activity` is not on the top of the stack will not be visible to call this method on, under normal circumstances.

Use this in your `onClick()`

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, NextActivityName.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

[Intent Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

From the Docs

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.

Comment: Thank you, so the only thing I'm confused about in the docs is that do i have to go through that process(writing the 3 lines) every time i want to go to that activity or only the 1st time when i originally start it? so for example i origionally start the activity with those 3 lines, then the next time i want to go back to it all i say is startActivity(i) or do i have set the flag again?

Comment: You need to do it this way every time but if you are reusing it then you can put it in a function or whatever to call depending on how you're calling this

Comment: starting Activity wont cause adding it to again to back track (new instance of that Activity ) ?

Comment: @sasan using this flag, no. It Will just bring the existing instance to the front. Not using any flags will create a new instance of it.

Comment: so it behave like default back navigation ( onResume () for first Activity ) ?

Comment: @sasan yes but this is useful if you have multiple activities on top of the one that you want to pull back up. Give it a try.