# Customize back navigation

Tags: android, back-stack, android-navigation, onbackpressed

First of all I read [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) but is kind of  complicated for me  . All I need is to go to an activity I want (navigate if exist in back stack or start it with Intent if it's not ) in onBackPressed() override . should I manage back stack
or something else ? if yes how ? and if no what is a simple way for that ?

P.S : I dont use ActionBar

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? How you can go back to the previous activity on the stack?

Comment: @AppPhil I dont want default action for back navigation (go to previous activity ) , I need to go somewhere else depend on situation

Comment: Then you need to override the onBackPressed() method. In there you do not call super.onBackPressed() (then you will not go to previous acitivity). In your onBackPressed() you can then start another activity you want to.

Comment: @AppPhil starting an Activity wont cause calling onCreate() in Activity life cycle ? notice that I want to resume it like what default back navigation does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:  as [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049394/2758345) and according to comments  ,  if we want to just bring an (existing )Activity to front , setting Intent flag to :

```
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
```

wont create new instance of Activity we want and just bring it front . this would be useful if we  have multiple activities on top of the one .

Answer (score 1):

you should override the second activity's `onBackPressed()` method and add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to your first activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` this will launch the first activity from backstack or create new if it doesn't exist in backstack.

Comment: is that mean if first Activity exist just pause that and don't add it again to back stack ?

Comment: yes. there will only be one instance of the activity on back stack.

Answer (score 1):

Use startActivityForResult() wherever needed. Do not create new instances of the same activity. That is, if u want to go back to the previous activity, just call `finish()` from this activity.

[Understand different launchmodes](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

As mentioned in the link above, `singleInstance` launchMode might be tricky and might cause issues.

Comment: after I used startActivityForResult() in first Activity , now how to go to another Activity from second Activities  back navigation ?

Comment: Just use `startActivity()`. If you want to comeback to the First when u press back in the Third Activity, call `finish()` when you call `startActvity()` in the second.